# IOT Central - Reported properties issue

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

I'm having an issue getting Reported properties to update/display properly when sending from the device.  I'm using the starter code provided in the IOT Central/ IOT Hub docs.  Code below.  When the function runs it reports back success yet when viewing the properties of the device in IOT Central they are not displayed.  I have verified that the property names are configured correctly in the device template but I'm obviously missing something.  I also changed the names of the properties in the code below to see if I would receive an error, but it still reported success.  Any ideas?

function sendDeviceProperties(twin) {
    var properties = {
      serialNumber: '123-ABC',
      manufacturer: 'Test Manufacturer'
    };
    twin.properties.reported.update(properties, (err) => console.log(`Sent device properties;` +
      (err ? `error: ${err.toString()}` : `status: success`)));
  }

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out what I was doing wrong...I set up the Property in the device template as an application property as opposed to a device property.

Comment: please mark this as accepted answer. SO keeps featuring this question as if you still need help