# Azure IoT Central - Device Property [Toggle] values on UI

Tags: azure-iot-central

My Template contains evice Property, type: Toggle.
I have set Property value = **true**
I see toggle in ON mode on the device properties page, but on Device Set Greeds this value is always OFF.
How to fix this issue?

Device properties page (ON):
[image]

Device Set Greed (OFF):
[image: ()]

Comment: Are you playing with simulated devices? Is this a real device? Is it possible for you to share some code were you are handling the property changes?

Comment: It is production Real device. Node.js code: 
sendDeviceProperties(twin,{'is_testing_update_channel':true});
Question is why IoT Central UI shows the different values

Comment: Have you seen this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53207787/iot-central-reported-properties-issue?rq=1

Comment: @AlbertoVega-MSFT yes, the property value has been set and it is display correctly on the Device Page -> Properties. But in Device Set Grid this and only this value displays wrong.

Comment: Can you please file a support request @ https://aka.ms/azsupt? If you do not have access to a support plan, please reach out @ AZCommunity@microsoft.com with a link to this thread as well as your subscription ID and we can help get the support ticket opened.